# How can I activate the sockets extension in my php?

Tags: php, wordpress, sockets, server, directadmin

I wanted to ask about how to activate the sockets extension of my php.
I have tried uncommenting the line "extension=sockets" but it gives me the following error afterwards:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sockets'

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Which PHP version? Which operating system? Linux: sockets.so, Windows sockets.dll - the extension is necessary with older PHP versions. However the shared library must be available as well.

Comment: my php version is 7.4, I have tried to put "extension=sockets.so" in the php.ini but it gives me the same error :(, I have linux on my server

Comment: Yes, the .so file must exist as well. Otherwise the answer to the question is: You can't activate an extension that does not exist. Perhaps the question you're asking is not the actual problem?

Comment: So, I would change the question to "how can I put the library that is not found, where can I download it, and in what path do I put it"

Comment: Which Linux Distro are you using? How did you install PHP? How did you install the installed PHP extensions (non-core ones). What is the name of the package of the PHP extension you want to install?

Comment: - ubuntu 20.04
- the php was installed automatically with the web administration panel "direct admin"
- Currently I have not installed any extension
- I don't know the name of the package to install, I don't know which one is necessary for the sockets.so library

I needed to activate the sockets extension, to do a practice of web sockets with php, but my knowledge is not enough to solve the error that I showed you

Comment: Please contact the support of "direct admin" they should have all the details present to serve you.